# Java Web Injection (Vraptor) + Websphere 8.5: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type EntityManager with qualifiers @Default

Tags: java, web, websphere-8, vraptor

I am trying to deploy a .war that was running on Tomcat 8 Container to an Application Server Websphere 8.5.

Im  using a mvc framework Vraptor 4, that uses dependency injection.

and getting this execption when start the aplication.

Any ideas please?
Is there any steps that i need to do on the server configuration, or the problem is just in the aplication? libs or dependencies...

```
         javax.enterprise.inject.AmbiguousResolutionException: There is more than one api type with : br.com.caelum.vraptor.Result with qualifiers : Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
    for injection into 
     Method Injection Point, method :  public void br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.download.DownloadObserver.download(br.com.caelum.vraptor.events.MethodExecuted,br.com.caelum.vraptor.Result) throws java.io.IOException, Bean Owner : [-1470479322,Name:null,WebBeans Type:MANAGED,API Types:[br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.download.DownloadObserver,java.lang.Object],Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any]]
         InjectionType   :  [interface br.com.caelum.vraptor.Result]
         Annotated       :  [Annotated Parameter,Base Type : interface br.com.caelum.vraptor.Result,Type Closures : [class java.lang.Object, interface br.com.caelum.vraptor.Result],Annotations : [],Position : 1]
         Qualifiers      :  [[@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]]
    found beans: 
    344531471,Name:null,WebBeans Type:MANAGED,API Types:[br.com.caelum.vraptor.util.test.MockResult,br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.AbstractResult,java.lang.Object,br.com.caelum.vraptor.Result,br.com.caelum.vraptor.util.test.MockSerializationResult],Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any]
    1922347074,Name:null,WebBeans Type:MANAGED,API Types:[br.com.caelum.vraptor.util.test.MockResult,br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.AbstractResult,java.lang.Object,br.com.caelum.vraptor.Result],Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any]
    -1060459643,Name:null,WebBeans Type:MANAGED,API Types:[br.com.caelum.vraptor.util.test.MockResult,br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.AbstractResult,java.lang.Object,br.com.caelum.vraptor.util.test.MockHttpResult,br.com.caelum.vraptor.Result],Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any]
    -155872150,Name:null,WebBeans Type:MANAGED,API Types:[br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultResult,br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.AbstractResult,java.lang.Object,br.com.caelum.vraptor.Result],Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any]
        at org.apache.webbeans.util.InjectionExceptionUtils.throwAmbiguousResolutionExceptionForBeans(InjectionExceptionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.webbeans.util.InjectionExceptionUtils.throwAmbiguousResolutionException(InjectionExceptionUtils.java:126)
        at org.apache.webbeans.container.ResolutionUtil.checkResolvedBeans(ResolutionUtil.java:101)
        at org.apache.webbeans.container.InjectionResolver.checkInjectionPoints(InjectionResolver.java:197)
        at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.validate(BeanManagerImpl.java:1169)
        at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.validate(BeansDeployer.java:394)
        at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.validateInjectionPoints(BeansDeployer.java:332)
        at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:183)
        at org.apache.webbeans.lifecycle.AbstractLifeCycle.startApplication(AbstractLifeCycle.java:124)
        at org.apache.webbeans.web.lifecycle.WebContainerLifecycle.startApplication(WebContainerLifecycle.java:77)
        at com.ibm.ws.webbeans.common.CommonLifeCycle.startApplication(CommonLifeCycle.java:106)
        at com.ibm.ws.webbeans.services.JCDIServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(JCDIServletContainerInitializer.java:85)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:620)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:901)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1211)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1450)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1032)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:795)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1413)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2273)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:654)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5572)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5698)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1303)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:666)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:91)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:246)
        at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:628)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1404)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:196)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:968)
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:515)
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:336)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:949)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1187)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInboundPostHandshake(SSLConnectionLink.java:768)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyHandshakeCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:464)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLUtils.handleHandshake(SSLUtils.java:1137)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLHandshakeIOCallback.complete(SSLHandshakeIOCallback.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>bradesco.solucaoaqui</groupId>
<artifactId>solucaoaquiv2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>
        ${project.artifactId}
    </finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.caelum</groupId>
        <artifactId>vraptor</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0-RC3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>15.0</version>
      <classifier>cdi1.0</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.caelum.vraptor</groupId>
        <artifactId>vraptor-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.34</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.269</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <!--    INTEGRACAO SOAP IMATEC -->
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
        <version>0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp.encoder</groupId>
        <artifactId>encoder</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: This looks weird to me - your error is reporting 4 possible candidates for injection, but three of them are mock results (going by their names), and so they should not be part of the JAR file that gets included here.  If they are included, I sort of expected this to always be a problem ...

Comment: yes, too weird... it looks like is a general cdi injection problem on the project, maybe because of the classpath but i dont know where to start to look for.

Answer (score 0):

"Servlet Containers supported are:

Tomcat 7 (+ Weld 2.x jars)
Jetty 8 and 9 (+ Weld 2.x jars)
To use the mentioned Servlet Containers its also necessary to add Weld 2.x jars and the following listener to your web.xml file to activate CDI:"

`<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
</listener>`

source PT-BR: http://www.vraptor.org/pt/docs/dependencias-e-pre-requisitos/

source EN: http://www.vraptor.org/en/

Comment: Hi cvdr, thanks for de reply, but the application is actually running fine on Containers, the problem is when i try to deploy on a Application Server (Websphere), i know by the VRaptor documentation that Websphere is not officially tested but the WAS 8.5 server is a requirement in this project...

Comment: Hmm - so this could be it, I guess.. IBM says you would want to be running WebSphere 8.5.5 for CDI 1.0, and 8.5.5.6 for CDI 1.2 (which is what Weld 2.2 implements).  So you may need to upgrade your version of WebSphere just a tiny bit... https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1605_stephen-trs/1605_stephen.html

Comment: You are right, WAS 8.5 doesnt support CDI 1.1+, so i did upgrade to WAS 9.0, and now im getting an... WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type EntityManager with qualifiers @Default for all my persistence classes... any tip?